# compare items using nested for loop

Tags: vb.net

I have list of desktopname that are coming from a class object. Below is the class object where each node has desktopid, desktopname etc.

```
<XmlType([Namespace]:="http://vanguard.com/csif/CSIFConfiguration.xsd")>
Public Class DesktopGroupRoleMappingType
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public businessfunction As String
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public desktopid As Integer
    <XmlIgnore>
    Public desktopidSpecified As Boolean
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public desktopname As String
```

as of now we are adding desktop name to list using below code.

```
For Each desktopMapping As DesktopGroupRoleMappingType In desktopGroupRoleMappings
    If lstDesktops.Items.IndexOf(desktopMapping.desktopname.Trim) < 0 Then
        lstDesktops.Items.Add(desktopMapping.desktopname.Trim)  '& " (" & desktopMapping.businessfunction.Trim & ")")
    End If
Next
```

Now I need to remove two of the desktop name from the list based on desktopID, so I have added a config entry like below. Now my question is, how can I remove desktop name from list.

```
<add  key ="Test" value="152,155"/>
```

Comment: Do you want to remove them after they were already added to the list, or do you just want to skip adding them to the list in the first place?

Comment: I am okie with both, either skip before adding or remove after adding to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Since the list only contains the name, you won't be able to find the items by ID and remove them, once they have already been added.  There are ways to solve that.  For instance, if you overrode the `ToString` method on `DesktopGroupRoleMappingType`, to make it return the name, like this:

```
<XmlType([Namespace]:="http://vanguard.com/csif/CSIFConfiguration.xsd")>
Public Class DesktopGroupRoleMappingType
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public businessfunction As String
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public desktopid As Integer
    <XmlIgnore>
    Public desktopidSpecified As Boolean
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public desktopname As String
    Public Function ToString() As String
        Return desktopname
    End Function
End Class
```

Then you could add the whole object to the list rather than just the name:

```
lstDesktops.Items.Add(desktopMapping)
```

Once you have the whole object in the list, then you could search through it to find the ones to remove.

However, if you don't even need to remove them after the fact, and it's sufficient to just skip adding them in the first place, then that's even easier.  Just filter the unwanted ones out before adding them:

```
If Not unwantedIds.Contains(desktopMapping.desktopid) Then
    lstDesktops.Items.Add(desktopMapping.desktopname.Trim)
End If
```